# Define pagination page_size per-view in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

Since version `3.3` it's not longer possible to define page_size on the view, as it's moved to the paginator class. [related deprecations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.3-announcement/#deprecations)

Our API has different page_sizes defined for different views and it feels ambiguous to add new paginator subclasses just to overwrite the page_size attribute. I cannot instantiate the paginator class in the view definition and use the `__init__` method as it's instantiated [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L163). I could overwrite this and make it a method what returns an instance instantiated with the right parameters, but as its name is not `get_pagination_class`, probably it's not a good idea.

My question is what would be the cleanest way to dynamically create a paginator class with the proper `page_size` attribute set?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432985/django-rest-framework-override-page-size-in-viewset) question, and I'd like to avoid both of its solutions.

Comment: It's really super-annoying that they changed this, it must be one of the most common alterations of the pagination and you should not have to derive new classes just to change that parameter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can achieve something relatively clean:

---

- Assuming you are setting the pagination per class with the
  `pagination_class` attribute.
- Assuming that you keep the `page_size` attribute in your class.

---

1. In your `settings.py` add a global pagination setting:

   ```
   'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
   'PAGE_SIZE': default_page_size,
   ```

   You can handle with this all the views that have the same page size.
2. For any other view/viewset:

   ```
   class ACustomViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, 
                        mixins.DestroyModelMixin, 
                        viewsets.GenericViewSet):

       pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
       page_size = N
       pagination_class.page_size = self.page_size
   ```

   Or you can do this inside a method:

   ```
   def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       self.pagination_class.page_size = self.page_size 
       ...
   ```

Comment: Hi John, I'm having some troubles with this code, basically I have 3 days learning python now, because I was assigned to fix a Python project, I'm still not quite familiar with the language, so can I ask you where should `N` and `self` would be defined in the `class ACustomViewSet`? Could there be any trouble if I have `mixins.CreateModelMixin` instead of `mixins.DestroyModelMixin`? Thank you

Comment: Hey @Frakcool, 1) `self` doesn't need an explicit definition in a python class. 2) `N` can be any positive integer to indicate how many results per page the response will have. 3) `DestroyModelMixin` provides a delete method and `CreateModelMixin` provides a create method, so there will be no problem by using just one of those, or both!
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks John, from 1) Python is throwing me a `Undefined variable: self`, from 2 and 3 I got it, what do you think the problem for `self` be? I'll keep looking for it then... Oh wait! I think I can just put: `pagination_class.page_size = page_size` isn't it?

Comment: Yeah @Frakcool, that is correct, I missed that! Good catch! I edited my answer :)

Comment: Fine! Thank you so much John! 1+ :) I still get it with the `self` at the right of `=` but deleting it from both sides I was able to do it

Comment: `self.pagination_class.page_size = self.page_size ` seems to set the page_size for all the view sets.

Comment: @Art No it sets the `page_size` of the ViewSet's (in the example `ACustomViewSet`)  instance of the pagination class.

Comment: Oops sorry, my bad I was using GenericView instead of GenericViewSet, If used in GenericView it seems to set page_size for all the views.

Answer (score 3):

I finally ended up with customizing it in a custom pagination. It seemed like the most neat and least hacky solution.

**The custom pagination**

```
from rest_framework import pagination

class CustomPageNumberPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    """Custom page number pagination."""

    page_size = 30
    max_page_size = 10000
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'

    def get_page_size(self, request):
        """Get page size."""
        # On certain pages, force custom/max page size.
        try:
            view = request.parser_context['view']
            if view.action in [
                'custom_page_size_view_1',
                'custom_page_size_view_2',
                # ...
                'custom_page_size_view_n',
            ]:
                return self.max_page_size
        except:
            pass

        return super(CustomPageNumberPagination, self).get_page_size(request)
```

**The view**

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route
from .pagination import CustomPageNumberPagination

class MyView(ModelViewSet):

    pagination_class = CustomPageNumberPagination

    @list_route()
    def custom_page_size_view_1(self, request):
        """Custom page size view 1"""

    @list_route()
    def custom_page_size_view_2(self, request):
        """Custom page size view 2"""

    @list_route()
    def custom_page_size_view_3(self, request):
        """Custom page size view 3"""
```