# Pagination not working in DRF even while extending the class from generics

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination

Pagination does not seem to work for me. I am even extending my class from generics, but still it doesn't seem to work.
Here is the code for my class

```
class RequestInvite(ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    serializer_class = RequestInviteSerializer
    http_method_names = ['post', 'get']
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

And here is the code snippet for my settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20
}
```

- Haven't used any custom pagination class
- Even defined a default pagination class

Still the pagination just does not seem to work.

Comment: What results are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a pagination class and setting it as the pagination_class to the `APIView`

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class RequestInvitePagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 20

class RequestInvite(ListCreateAPIView):
    .....
    pagination_class = RequestInvitePagination
```

---

To make the default work, check if your settings are getting overridden somewhere?

```
class RequestInvite(ListCreateAPIView):
    ...
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.pagination_class)
        return super(RequestInvite, self).get(request, args, kwargs)

from django.conf import settings
print(settings.REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS'], "pagination class")
print(settings.REST_FRAMEWORK['PAGE_SIZE'], "page size")
```

check if the two matches..

Comment: Quiet weird, you are right. Settings are getting overridden somewhere. The pagination class is None for the view class. I am accepting this answer. However, can you let me know in what possible scenarios the settings can get overridden?

Comment: have a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432985/django-rest-framework-override-page-size-in-viewset